# Saving new records and updating in Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I am currently invastigating problem with my DB and it seems very strange to me. I have 2 records with 2 columns - status and fighter_name. and i have a constraint idx_status_fighter - i cannot have fighters with same name and active status. I have 2 records in DB. "Zed" with status ACTIVE and "Zed" with status DELETED. In transactional method first I set the status of active zed to DELETED and then the status of deleted Zed to active and Spring tells me that I have ViolationConstraint about the idx_status_fighter. I really cannot find any information about that.

Edit: As far as I know @Transactional commits to DB after the whole method ends without errors. How can I instruct him which commits to DB to set first.

Comment: can you update with your method signature and db update code. This seems, after your first update you are flushing the state to DB which is violating your uniqekey constraint.

Comment: DB is not updated, because its transactional method. The code is straight forward - i set the status from active to deleted and then save in the database. And then i change the status to the other record from deleted to active and call repository.save.